# java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""?

Tags: string, text, double, tostring, gettext

I'm not sure how to fix this problem.
I have a spinner. When a certain choice is selected then whatever is in the text field (number) I want to use that value for a specific method.

In Main:

```
EditText temp;
temp = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);



public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
{

String choice = parent.getSelectedItem().toString();
Double value = Double.parseDouble(temp.getText().toString());
}
```

Everything works fine before I try to convert the temp into a double, it crashes the application. Any help will be appreciated.

I AM NEW TO ANDROID STUDIO.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NumberFormatException error (parseInt)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5267241/numberformatexception-error-parseint)

Comment: I've also tried 
    Double value = new Double(temp.getText().toString());

Answer (score 0):

I think the temp field is empty (hence the ""), which does not parse well as a double.

Comment: I want the user to enter a value in the text field, so do I have to initialize a String to temp in order for it to work?